# Can Arduino Send Data to Rails Server using REST API method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, api, server, arduino

Can We send data from arduino that using ethernet or wifi shield to RAILS server using API? If it possibly to be done, can you tell me which library and how to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can make calls to RESTful APIs from Arduino through ethernet or wifi shields. I prefer using standard libraries such as [Ethernet / Ethernet 2](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Ethernet).

Here is a sample (ethernet) implementation for your reference:

```
#include <Ethernet2.h>
#include <EthernetClient.h>
#include <EthernetUdp2.h>
#include <util.h>

IPAddress _ip(192, 168, 1, 12); // Client (Arduino) IP address
byte _mac[] = {0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x11, 0x3C, 0x69}; // Arduino mac address
char _server[] = "192.168.1.10"; // Server IP address
int _port = 9200; // Server port number
EthernetClient _client;

void setup() {    
  Ethernet.begin(_mac, _ip);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("Local IP: ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());

  if (_client.connect(_server, _port)) {
    Serial.println("SUCCESS: Connected to the server!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("ERROR: Connection failed to the server!");
    return;
  }
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {       
  // JSON formatted data package including sample 
  // 'temperature', 'humidity', and 'timestamp' values
  String data = "{\"temperature\": " + String(temperature) + ", " +
    "\"humidity\": " + String(humidity) + ", " +
    "\"timestamp\": " + String(timestamp) + "}";

  String url = "/my-api/savedata"; // API url hosted on the server

  // Finally, make an API call: POST request
  _client.print("POST " + url + " HTTP/1.1 \r\n" +
    "Content-Type: application/json \r\n" +
    "Content-Length: " + data.length() + " \r\n" +
    "\r\n" + data);

  delay(500); // Give the network some time

  // Read all the lines of the reply from server and 
  // print them to Serial to validate your API call
  while (_client.available()) {
    String reply = _client.readStringUntil('\r');
    Serial.print(reply);
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```